# How to render a byte array (Blob) as image using TagLib

Tags: grails, groovy

How to render an Image file (Blob) stored in the database using a custom tag, I used to render a logo but the image is being crashed and the output is the byte array.

This is what I tried:

```
def logo = { attrs, body ->
    if(session?.companyId && session?.companyId != 'null'){
        Company company = Company.findById(session?.companyId)
        if (!company || !company?.logo) {
            println "No response..."
            out <<"<img src='/cdc/static/images/logo.png' width='150' height='70' />"
        }
        else{
            println "Writing..."
            out << "<img src='"
            out << company?.logo
            out << "' width='150' height='70' />"
        }
    }
    else{
        println "No response..."
        //out <<"<img src='/cdc/static/images/logo.png' width='150' height='70' />"
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

[image]

How can the **company?.logo** be rendered as an **image** and not a **byte array** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want to provide a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), basically. For that you'll want something like:

```
src="data:img/png;base64,xxx"
```

where "xxx" is the data in base64 format.

So for example, using [this public domain base64 library](http://iharder.net/base64):

```
out << "<img src='data:img/png;base64,"
out << Base64.encode(company?.logo)
out << "' width='150' height='70' />"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this same thing in Grails 3.0.11, and the Base64.encode line gave me an error.  This is the resulting taglib that I came up with, which works great for me:

```
/** imgFromByteArray
 *
 * Print a byte array as an image tag.
 *
 * attrs:
 *      1. String imageType         Example: image/jpeg
 *      2. byte[] imageContent
 *      #. Any additional attrs will be included in the <img /> tag
 */
def imgFromByteArray = { attrs ->

    //Get image content and type from attrs
    byte[] imageContent = attrs.imageBytes
    String imageType = attrs.imageType

    //Remove attributes that should not be printed in the img tag
    ['imageBytes', 'imageType'].each{
        if(attrs.containsKey(it)){ attrs.remove(it) }
    }

    //Print the image tag with image content
    out << """<img src='data:${imageType};base64,${imageContent?.encodeBase64()}'"""

    //Include any other tags given
    attrs.each { attrLabel, attrValue ->
        out << " ${attrLabel}=\"${attrValue}\""
    }

    //Close the image tag
    out<< "/>"
}
```